# Sync.WaitGroup, why closer in a goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

Below is the example code in the Go programming book. I do not understand why the closer needs to be its own goroutine. I tried to move the **closer** into the main but it crashes. Somebody could explain why the closer needs to be in a separate goroutine?

Thanks!

```
func makeThumbnails(filenames <-chan string, result chan<- int64) int64 {
  sizes := make(chan int64)
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  for f := range filenames {
      wg.Add(1)
      go func(f string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        sizes <- int64(len(f))
      }(f)
  }

  // **closer**, why this guy needs to be in a goroutine???
  go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(sizes)
  }()

  var total int64
  for size := range sizes {
    total += size
  }
  result <- total
  return total
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `sizes` is not a buffered `chan`, so only one of the anonymous goroutines can actually complete before `sizes` needs to be read from. That makes `wg.Wait()` wait forever (since the next goroutine is blocking on `sizes <-` and can't `defer wg.Done()`) and deadlocks.

By throwing the closer in a separate goroutine, it can close the `sizes` chan whenever it's ready to do so, and process from `sizes` in between. Ultimately this is a great use of a goroutine -- fire and forget closing!

To make this code work without the closer goroutine, you can simply initialize `sizes` as a buffered chan with a buffer >= the length of `filenames`.

```
func makeThumbnails(filenames <-chan string, result chan<- int64) int64 {
    sizes := make(chan int64, 10) // buffered channel, now!
    // if filenames sends more than 10 strings, though, we're in trouble!!

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for f := range filenames {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(f string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            sizes <- int64(len(f))
        }(f)
    }

    // **closer**, this guy doesn't need to be a goroutine!!
    wg.Wait()
    close(sizes)

    var total int64
    for size := range sizes {
        total += size
    }
    result <- total
    return total
}
```

However since `filenames`'s length is unknowable at runtime, it's not possible to do this easily. You'd have to read through `filenames`, store it into a slice, then initialize sizes and `for` over `range filenamesSlice` and.... yeah basically you've just re-written the whole function at that point.